# Why is the reverse in a python List not equal unless you declare a new List?

Tags: python, reverse

Im writing code to check if a number is a valid palindrome, given we can delete at MOST one character in the list somewhere. I have the logic all worked out, but for some reason when I check the reverse against itself without declaring it to a new List, it will return False for "abcd" but True when I do declare the check to new variables.

In case the question is confusing, "aba" is True, "abba" is True, "abbca" is true (delete the c and it's a palindrome), "abcd" is False

So this code is incorrect:

```
def validPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:

        
        left, right = 0, len(s) - 1
        while left < right:
            if s[left] != s[right]:
                return (s[left+1:right+1] == s[left+1:right+1:-1]) or (s[left:right] == s[left:right:-1])
            left += 1
            right -= 1
        return True
```

but this is True:

```
def validPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:

        
        left, right = 0, len(s) - 1
        while left < right:
            if s[left] != s[right]:
                one, two = s[left+1:right+1], s[left:right]
                return one == one[::-1] or two == two[::-1]
            left += 1
            right -= 1
        return True
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Because `s[left+1:right+1:-1]` won't reverse `s[left:+1:right+1]`. Since `left + 1 <= right +1`, the a negative step will always be empty. You should try using a few debugging prints, or a debugger to step through the code and see, or experiment with examples. You don't "declare it as a new list", *python doesn't have variable declarations*. And *slicing always produces a new list object*. You *assign it to a variable*, although you probably should for readability's sake, that isn't required, you could do `s[left+1:right+1] == s[left+1:right+1][::-1]`

Comment: `s[left+1:right+1:-1])` is not equivalent to `s[::-1]` and it's value is chaning in your code continusly and is not consistant like `s[::-1]`

Comment: Show your list & expected output.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks guys, cleared up my misunderstanding. Appreciate it! :)

Comment: @sahasrara62 thanks guys, cleared up my misunderstanding. Appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's try a simpler example:

```
>>> example = 'foobar'
>>> example[2:4:-1]
''
>>> example[2:4][::-1]
'bo'
```

When the stride for the slice is negative, the start point has to be "after" the end point, or else the resulting slice is empty. Python starts at `example[2]` and goes *backwards*, and finds that it has already "passed" element 4, so nothing is included. To make this work in one step, we would need to reverse the indices, but also subtract 1 because of the fact that the start point is included but the end point is excluded...

```
>>> example[4:2:-1]
'ab'
>>> example[3:1:-1]
'bo'
```

Thus, in the original code:

```
return (s[left+1:right+1] == s[right:left:-1]) or (s[left:right] == s[right-1:left-1:-1])
```

Comment: this fails on something like "eccer" - where it goes into the 
```
s[left:right] == s[right-1:left-1:-1]
```
where s[right-1:left-1:-1] = s[3:-1:-1]

any way around that?

Comment: Honestly, I would just stick with the two-step approach. It's easier to understand, too.